# how to host service and website on windows azure platform

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, azure, azure-sql-database

we have a service built in azure environment. and a website which consume webservice we need to host it in windows azure platform. we have tried a lot but not succeeded. And little bit we are confused whether we are going in right direction or not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2011/01/hosting-a-public-web-site-and-an-internal-services-site-in-one-windows-azure-web-role.html) describes how to do what you're trying

Answer (score 0):

If you manually modify you service definition file, you can add additional virtual directories or applications to the same site (and the same port number).

Your service definition file will look like this:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzureProject">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <VirtualDirectory name="Foo" physicalDirectory="..\Bar" /> 
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

You web role will be deployed to the site root, and a virtual directory will be created in IIS called Foo. This will contain the files stored in the 'Bar' directory of your local machine.

You can also add a 'VirtualApplication' tag instead, depending on what configuration you want in IIS.